# Write a procedure stream-limit that finds

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

From [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-24.html):

> Exercise 3.64.  Write a procedure
>   stream-limit that takes as arguments a
>   stream and a number (the tolerance).
>   It should examine the stream until it
>   finds two successive elements that
>   differ in absolute value by less than
>   the tolerance, and return the second
>   of the two elements. Using this, we
>   could compute square roots up to a
>   given tolerance by

```
(define (sqrt x tolerance)
  (stream-limit (sqrt-stream x) tolerance))
```

I wrote this answer:

```
(define (stream-limit s tol)
  (if (stream-null? s) 
      (error "End of stream found before limit reached:" tol)
      (let* ((a (stream-car s))
             (b (stream-car (stream-cdr s)))
             (diff (abs (- a b))))
        (if (> tol diff) b (stream-limit (stream-cdr s) tol)))))
```

Can it be improved?

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me.  I would only suggest changing `(> tol diff)` to `(< diff tol)` because it reads more like the problem specification and is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good. Is it OK to just say it looks good? If it's not, here are two comments:

- Why do you use `let*` here? Isn't `let` enough?
- You could define `stream-cadr`.

Comment: The initializer for `diff` uses the values of `a` and `b`.  Since `let` doesn't create the variable bindings until *after* evaluating all of the initializer expressions, it won't work here.